# Rails and net-ssh/sftp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh, net-ssh, net-sftp

I am developing an app that need to be constantly connected to ssh.

Every action open a new ssh connection and new sftp-server on the target host, I was wondering if there is a solution for keep session ssh/sftp without create new connection.

With ajax calls I have too many sftp-server daemons running... (I can set timeout to few seconds but not resolve constants connections)

Tried to serialize ssh object but dont work and see on a question it's impossible

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Store ssh/sftp and object in a global variable work great http://pastie.org/2662772

Comment: argh work great with webrick/mongrel... not passenger (production&development)

Comment: another edit and the last ! ssh/sftp connections with passenger depend of PassengerMaxPoolSize.